# Alternative for giant nested ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
Period No.  Frequency
1           Month
2           Month
3           Month
3           Quarter
6           Quarter     
9           Quarter
1           YTD
2           YTD
3           YTD
```

I want to add on a column called "Period" whose values are determined by what is in the Period No. AND Frequency columns. So:

```
Period No.  Frequency  Period
1           Month      1
2           Month      2
3           Month      3
3           Quarter    Q1
6           Quarter    Q2 
9           Quarter    Q3
1           YTD        YTD-Jan
2           YTD        YTD-Feb
3           YTD        YTD-Mar
```

Right now, I'm using nested if statements to do this. For example:

```
data$Period <-
  ifelse(
    (data$`Period No.` == '3') & (data$Frequency == 'Q1'), 'Q1',
    ifelse(
      (data$`Period No.` == '6') & (data$Frequency == 'Q2'), 'Q2',
      ifelse(
        (data$`Period No.` == '9') & (data$Frequency == 'Q3'), 'Q3', 'ERROR'
)
)
)
```

If I were to do this for every month for each iteration of Frequency, I would have 30 nested ifelse statements. I'm wondering if there's a more concise method to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only really need to *nest* `ifelse` statements if the conditions themselves are nested. In this case, the conditions are mutually exclusive, so you can assign to each set individually. We can also be a little clever about creating your results with `paste` and some math rather than listing all the possibilities:

```
df$Period[df$Frequency == "Month"] = as.character(df$Period_No[df$Frequency == "Month"])
df$Period[df$Frequency == "Quarter"] = paste0("Q", (df$Period_No[df$Frequency == "Quarter"] - 1) %/% 3 + 1)
df$Period[df$Frequency == "YTD"] = paste0("YTD-", month.abb[df$Period_No[df$Frequency == "YTD"]])

df
#   Period_No Frequency  Period
# 1         1     Month       1
# 2         2     Month       2
# 3         3     Month       3
# 4         3   Quarter      Q1
# 5         6   Quarter      Q2
# 6         9   Quarter      Q3
# 7         1       YTD YTD-Jan
# 8         2       YTD YTD-Feb
# 9         3       YTD YTD-Mar
```

If you like `dplyr`, I'd recommend the `case_when` function:

```
df %>% mutate(Period = case_when(
    Frequency == "Month" ~ as.character(Frequency),
    Frequency == "Quarter" ~ paste0("Q", (Period_No - 1) %/% 3 + 1),
    Frequency == "YTD" ~ paste0("YTD-", month.abb[Period_No])
))
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = "Period_No  Frequency
1           Month
2           Month
3           Month
3           Quarter
6           Quarter     
9           Quarter
1           YTD
2           YTD
3           YTD", header = T)
```